# Array push method is duplicating elements and the new Set method is not deleting duplicated elements

Tags: javascript

I am building a Prime Number multiplication table. I have written the code to get the Prime Numbers depending on the Range the User gives but when I push that prime number to an array. I get duplicates. I tried to get rid of the array using ES6 new set method before looping through them but I still get those duplicates.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('.form');
let formParent = form.parentNode;
let primeNumberArray = [];
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let startValue = parseInt(document.querySelector('.start').value);
  let endValue = parseInt(document.querySelector('.end').value);
  let table = document.createElement('table');
  for (let i = startValue; i <= endValue; i++) {
    let flag = 0;

    // looping through 2 to user input number
    for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) {
      if (i % j == 0) {
        flag = 1;
        break;
      }
    }

    // if number greater than 1 and not divisible by other numbers
    if (i > 1 && flag == 0) {
      primeNumberArray.push(i);
      let uniqueArray = [...new Set(primeNumberArray)]
      console.log(uniqueArray)
      for (var k = 0; k < uniqueArray.length; k++) {
        (function(k) {
          table.innerHTML += `<tr>
               <th>${uniqueArray[k]}</th>
              </tr>`
        }(k));
      }
      formParent.insertBefore(table, form.nextSibling)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <fieldset>
    <label>start</label>
    <input type="number" class="start" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <label>end</label>
    <input type="number" class="end" />
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" value="run" />
</form>
```

Comment: I don't see duplicates in the array. You're just printing the array multiple times after each update.

Comment: Are you seeing duplicates **every** time the user clicks submit or only after the first time?

Comment: I'm not seeing any duplications going on. Can you please provide more info, like what inputs are you using?

Comment: The issue is that you are outputting the **entire** array **every** time that the loop has found a new prime number.  Wait until **after** the `for(..)` loop has finished before outputting anything

Comment: @VLAZ once you click on submit, it duplicates the numbers.

Comment: @newbiefatcoder the *array* doesn't have duplicate elements. I've converted your code to a runnable snippet - you can see it yourself. You get a single array with unique values every time you run it. However, every time you update the array you also show it, so you keep appending data to the page. Instead of appending, *replace* the data shown or only display it once and then you'd see a single unique set of numbers on the page.

Comment: @VLAZ.  I just saw it. The code works now. I moved it to outside the for loop.